# imgur api won't work

Tags: php, api, imgur

i have a question about the [imgur](http://imgur.com) api. 
I want to create a gallery for my website using the imgur api, but how can i create a file uploader that uploads to the imgur servers?

Here is what i created:

```
<?php
include 'xmlparser.php'; // From http://www.criticaldevelopment.net/xml/doc.php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
    $data = file_get_contents($_FILES["file"]['tmp_name']);

    // $data is file data
    $pvars   = array('image' => base64_encode($data), 'key' => HERE_MY_API_KEY);
    $timeout = 30;
    $curl    = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://api.imgur.com/2/upload.xml');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $timeout);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $pvars);

    $xml = curl_exec($curl);

    $parser = new XMLParser($xml);
    $parser->Parse();
    echo $parser->images->item->links->original;

    curl_close ($curl); 
}
else
{
    ?>
    <form action="test.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="file" id="file" /> 
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
    <?php
} 
?>
```

But this doesn't seem to work...?
I get this error:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ')' in C:\data\home\www\test.php on line 7

And line 7 is this row:

```
$pvars   = array('image' => base64_encode($data), 'key' => HERE_MY_API_KEY);
```

What is wrong?
The documentation of the imgur api is here:
[http://api.imgur.com/examples](https://api.imgur.com/examples)

Can you guys help me?

And yes, i already searched through these topics:

[HTML Upload Form will only upload files found in the directory of the PHP file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2625422/html-upload-form-will-only-upload-files-found-in-the-directory-of-the-php-file) 
[Using jQuery to parse XML returned from PHP script (imgur.com API)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2616675/using-jquery-to-parse-xml-returned-from-php-script-imgur-com-api)

But it didn't help me...

Greetings

Comment: Are you putting your API key in quotes?

Comment: @Daniel: No, the documentation said i must not do that...

Comment: Where in the documentation does it say that?

Comment: @Daniel, well, i looked at the example, so at the php example row 7.

Comment: It returns: "invalid api key", and its a valid one, checked in my profile.

Comment: Well then thats a separate issue than the PHP error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the API key in quote marks. The way they put it in all caps and outside quote marks is to signify a constant value.

Comment: That doens't work! It says the api is not correct while it is!

Comment: This solves your first problem. The 2nd problem is with your API key, not your PHP code now.

Comment: Well, yeah. Im gonna contact imgur about this. Thank you though.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you register for anonymous API and not Authenticated API here http://imgur.com/register/api

Pulled my hair off for this