# Why am I being redirected when attempting to register on imgur API?

Tags: api, imgur

https://apidocs.imgur.com step 2 says:

> Register your Application ( https://api.imgur.com/oauth2/addclient )

However, the above link does NOT work! Every time I attempt to register my app, I am redirected to https://myusername.imgur.com/all/

I have tried:

1. Both Chrome + Firefox.
2. Both "Incognito" type modes on both browsers.
3. VPN to other countries
4. Different computer
5. Watching YouTube videos for visuals that I'm going to the right place.
6. Ensured I'm looking at the latest and greatest API docs

I'm out of luck.

[image]

**EDIT:** I also found another URL that also just redirects me: https://imgur.com/register/api

Comment: Have you tried to modify settings, disabling the "Automatically follow redirects" setting ?

Comment: which Postman version do you use, app or chrome ?

Comment: I am using the postman app. However, I can't even get that far -- I'm supposed to directly visit this link before I even start the Postman processes to get the client key. Am I understanding the process wrong?

Comment: So it not a postman issue ... have a look at this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4986470/imgur-api-wont-work?rq=1 and maybe look for other ones, it may help you with your problem

Comment: Are you saying the URL above works for you?

Comment: no I didn't try, I just looked around to know what imgur is and I found that some people had issues with registering ...

Comment: ah, I see - Thanks for that. They listed another link (looks like an older API link). That one ALSO redirects me back to home. I asked others and it seems that the register link is broken. Seems like an imgur issue? I emailed support.

Comment: I think so ... we may get back in touch if postman issues occur  ;)  good luck

Comment: oh, by the way, if you end up solving the problem, don't hesitate to answer your own question so the community can benefit from it ...

Comment: Me too, can not access the client registration page.

Comment: Seems that it truly is broken. Im still awaiting a response from imgur support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The system was down without notice: It seems to be back up now. It was an imgur issue. The outage was ~1 week for new registrants.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Is Imgur having this issue again?